# Read API data using curl with GET method

Tags: api, curl

I am trying to read open source data available on "https://swapi.co/" using curl.
there is no authentication needed and only the GET Method could be used to query the schema and data according to their documentation.

I am having an error on the following command:
   curl -x GET "http://swapi.co/api/"
I am getting the following error message
   C:\Users*****>curl -x GET "http://swapi.co/api/"
curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: GET.

Any idea?

kindest regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-x` (lower case x) is for setting a proxy, and you told it the proxy is named GET. (Which obviously was wrong since it can't resolve such a host name.)

Remove the "-x GET" and it'll work.

Comment: Hi, I am new to curl and Bash. yeah had it to work when I had done that. Now you are giving me the reason. Thanks very much. Also found that  "-X GET" (upper case) worked